# Applying numeric format to a column in a pandas data frame that contains spaces as values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am facing a problem while applying a numeric format to columns in a data frame, As the columns contain non-numeric value (' ' as a value). I have tried to convert the columns into numeric and apply format to those columns and facing some errors.

So, is there a way of converting columns to numeric and apply format ignoring non-numeric values( only ' ' as value in this case)

Here is my piece of code i tried and facing errors. Any suggestions

`pd.to_numeric(df_both['col1','col2'],errors='ignore')
df_both[['col1','col2']] = df_both[['col1','col2']].replace({'nan':''},regex=True)
df_both['col1'] = df_both.apply(lambda x: "{:,}".format(x['col1']),axis=1)
df_both['col2'] = df_both.apply(lambda x: "{:,}".format(x['col2']),axis=1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try a simple `try` and `except` block to format the data accordingly.

```
def format(x):
    try:
        return "{:,}".format(float(x))
    except:
        return x

df_both['col1'] = df_both['col1'].apply(lambda x: format(x))
```